# Как исключить все строки, в которых есть знак «#» и далее текст?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

С CSS-файла парсятся все файлы регулярным выражением:

```
/url\((?!data)['\"]?\K[^)'\"]+/
```

Получается что-то типа такого:

```
fonts/BlissProExtraBold.eot
fonts/BlissProExtraBold.eot?#iefix
fonts/BlissProExtraBold.woff
fonts/BlissProExtraBold.ttf
fonts/BlissProExtraBold.svg#BlissProExtraBold
images/logo.png
images/problems__triangles.png
images/problems_problem1_number.png
images/problems_problem2_number.png
images/problems_problem3_number.png
```

Как исключить строки, которые имеют знак `#` и далее идущие символы? Возможно есть готовая функция в php?

Comment: Как вариант можно разделить строку по переносу - `\r\n` , а дальше фильтром отсеить элементы массива в которых есть символ `#`

Comment: если так https://regex101.com/r/ueKDsn/1

Comment: Можно просто добавить во второй класс символ `#`, получается следующее выражение: `/url\((?!data)['\"]?\K[^)'\"#]+/`. https://regex101.com/r/gbu3R4/1/